# Migrating Wordpress themes using Bootstrap from 2.3.2 to 3.3.7 (and higher)

Tags: css, wordpress, twitter-bootstrap

I'm set with the migration of several Wordpress themes that use Bootstrap 2.3.2. The choice is to use 3.3.7.

First off, I checked that there are no custom div IDs or classes used in the theme.

I then replaced the 2.3.2 CSS/JS Bootstrap files with the 3.3.7 equivalent files.

The layout was a mess as a result. Images are no longer responsive, and there is obvious viewport overflow in different devices.

- I have already noticed that the Wordpress posts and pages use HTML elements with Bootstrap styling directly applied.
- Does anyone here have experience with this kind of large scale task? What workflow did you apply to migrate Wordpres themes with Bootstrap from 2.3.2 to 3.3.7 quickly?**

I do not need to change the look and feel.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you looked at the migration [document here](http://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/migration/)? the migration document highlights all changes to classes and what you need to do. There are also online tools [like this one](http://code.divshot.com/bootstrap3_upgrader/) and [this tool](http://upgrade-bootstrap.bootply.com/v3) which you can try.